# Bootstrap v2: I don't understand how media query works

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I made my first media query! I added the following media query to my custom.css page:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
footer {
  background-color: red;
   }
}
```

I made the footer red so I can see how the media query works in action. When I expand my browser up to 1200px, the footer turns brown around 1183px which is BEFORE I reach 1200px even though I "told" the media query to stay red up to 1200px. Why is the red disappearing before I reach 1200px?

Live preview of my [site is here](http://www.ogmda.com/test/).

Edit: I noticed that the actual breakpoint is not 1200px, but 1183px...and that is when the footer turns red despite my media query written with  max-width:1200px.....

Comment: use `@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {`

Comment: Something to do with scroll bars or computations made as if scroll bars are present? 1200 - 1183 = 17 sounds like a likely scroll bar size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your medai queries look good to me.

Picking up on the comment by [@Kevin Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99692/kevin-reid), jQuery includes scroll bars in the window width calculations. If you use @media queries,  webkit browsers (eg Chrome and Safari) don't include scroll bars, though I've read comments from others that Firefox does include scroll bars in the media query calculation.

If you are asking because something isn't working as you expect on the page one detail to note is that your Bootstrap CSS changes its layout @ 1200 px with

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
... grid changes here ...
}
```

Your test is

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
footer {
background-color: red;
}
}
```

So it's actually out of sync with the bootstrap CSS by 1px. You could change it to

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
footer {
background-color: red;
}
}
```